# HDMI output on a Mac Mini

Tags: hdmi

Im considering purchasing a new Apple Mac Mini for use with a HD tv. However I really need to make sure that I will be able to hook it up - otherwise its a VERY expensive mistake!

When going through the purchase, there are extra peripherals such as Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter, Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter and Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter. However these do not seem to fit my need (unless Im mistaken) of needing HDMI - the input in the back of my TV.

Any advice appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter:
http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5311&seq=1&format=2

Please note: Audio may have to be transmitted via optical out.

Comment: You would be better off getting one of these, which redirects audio into the HDMI input on your TV:  http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=6331&seq=1&format=2

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and the existing answer has become outdated--

**The current generation Mac Mini has a built-in HDMI port that does support audio out!**